# Spring Cloud Config Server: error: No such label: master

Tags: java, spring, server, cloud, config

when I access the url http://localhost:8888/actuator/health y have this error

```json
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "details": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "status": "UP",
            "details": {
                "total": 457192763392,
                "free": 347865096192,
                "threshold": 10485760
            }
        },
        "refreshScope": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "configServer": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "details": {
                "repository": {
                    "application": "app",
                    "profiles": "default"
                },
                "error": "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: master"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my application.yml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKaPd.png)

Comment: Next time please post any source code as text, not as screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, spring cloud server tries to get properties from branch "master" in the git repository. [Your repository](https://github.com/adrianagirre9432/microservicios) doesn't have it (you have branch "main" instead).

You can use property `default-label` to set custom branch name (see [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.M3/multi/multi__appendix_compendium_of_configuration_properties.html)):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          default-label: main
```

Or, you can rename your branch to master and leave all other things as they are.

Comment: even though i added spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main it still gave me same error, but my problem was the wrong config file name

Answer (score 1):

Check your property file name and request file name.
I was getting same and resolved by making two below changes.

1st Change:
`spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=E:\\\\spring_microservice\\\\git-localconfig-repo`

Removed file///...... and added 4 slash (\\)

2nd Change:
Actually i was making request with incorrect property file name. I was making request like `http://localhost:8888/limit-servers/default` but correct file name is `limit-server.properties` so i have correct the request as below.

```
http://localhost:8888/limit-server/default
```

And it worked for me.

Comment: lol my problem was 2nd change, thanks :) filename was incorrect, but i am still getting the no label error even though i used spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
, but the source values are coming correct

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue, and resolved it by making the two below changes:

1. `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=E:/spring_microservice/git-localconfig-repo`
2. Added forward slash (`/`) everywhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add in your configuration file application.properties or apllication.yml, the following line of code :

*- For people that use application.properties file :*

spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main

*- For people that use application.use file :*

spring:
cloud:
config:
server:
git:
default-label: main